# Woocommerce Order By Billing Name

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help to order by billing first name and if that can't be done, group by customer_id.'

Right now I'm using `wc_get_orders($product_id);` Which works fine. It doesn't allow for any arguments.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: In this list do want to filter order by product ID, or only want to display all the order's in ASC order of `billing_first_name`?

Comment: filter by billing_first_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested here is the long version ...I'm sure there's a WP_Query version that's much simpler, I just wasn't able to figure it out.

`SELECT order_items.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS postmeta ON order_items.order_id = postmeta.post_id AND postmeta.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
                ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value DESC`

Answer (score 0):

```
$orders= wc_get_orders( array(
'orderby' => 'billing_first_name',
'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

Comment: Thank you...and that doesn't work. And I still need the product id. According to WC https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_orders.html it only accepts limit arguments. ( orderby string Order by date, title, id, modified, rand)